# Auto populate import path based on class name

Tags: angular

I am using Visual Studio with my angular 2 application, is there a way to auto populate the import path, just like with C# using statements and 'ctrl .' key combination. I find typing the imports too repetitive and misspelling is often a problem, it definitely slow me down.

Comment: You can create your own code snippet.

Comment: Create my own code snippet, hmm, would you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to Visual Studio 2015/2017 or VS Code? The current version of VS Code provides the lightbulb icon to complete the import statements for you just like with C# in VS 2015/2017.

Comment: The intellisense in VS Code works great for imports, I am looking for sort of the same functionality in Visual Studio 2015. Perhaps I should be using VS Code for Angular2 development, and Visual Studio for back end dev. BTW, love your tutorials Deborah, thx

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, most Angular/.NET devs I know use VS Code for Angular and VS 2015/2017 for the back-end. "The right tool for the right job" as they say. :-)